# LINQ, DataTable.Select() или выборка по дате

Tags: c#, linq

Есть табличка

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cassa` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pnumber` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `ypayment` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `nreceipt` INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pdate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ptime` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `freading1` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `consumption1` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `summ1` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `freading2` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `consumption2` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `summ2` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `oelectricity` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `lpayment` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment` DOUBLE(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `appointment` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8192 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Достаю все в DataSet и пытаюсь вытащить из него в нужное время.
Данные нужно вытащить по определенной выборке, вот так достаю по определенной дате

```
DataTable cassaBT = dateSet.Tables["cassa"].Select("pdate = '" + Convert.ToDateTime("2021-02-20") + "' and appointment not like 'Сальдо на%' and appointment not like ''").CopyToDataTable();
```

Нужно так же, но для месяца отдельно и для года отдельно.
Как реализовать?

Пока вышел из положения вот так

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateSet.Tables["cassa"].Columns.Count; i++)
    cassaBT.Columns.Add();
foreach (DataRow row in dateSet.Tables["cassa"].Rows)
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(row[4]).ToString("yyyy-MM") == Convert.ToDateTime(ts3CBox.SelectedItem).ToString("yyyy-MM"))
        cassaBT.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

Но это вообще не LINQ...

Вот код для теста

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace CassaJornalTest
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable cassaTable = new DataTable("cassa");
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("pnumber", typeof(int));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("ypayment", typeof(int));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("nreceipt", typeof(int));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("pdate", typeof(DateTime));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("ptime", typeof(string));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("freading1", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("consumption1", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("summ1", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("freading2", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("consumption2", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("summ2", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("oelectricity", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("lpayment", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("payment", typeof(double));
            cassaTable.Columns.Add("appointment", typeof(string));
            string[,] dataForTable = { { "1", "13", "2021", "5", "2021-01-29", "18:37", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "5500,00", "Членские взносы за текущий год" },
                                       { "2", "26", "2021", "4", "2021-02-26", "21:52", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "469,89", "Земельный налог" },
                                       { "3", "26", "2021", "3", "2021-02-26", "21:50", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "5500,00", "Членские взносы" },
                                       { "4", "0", "2021", "4", "2021-04-28", "17:09", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-5000,00", "Зачистка снега" },
                                       { "5", "0", "2021", "3", "2021-04-27", "20:17", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-6930,00", "Подотчет председателя" },
                                       { "6", "0", "2020", "2", "2020-01-19", "22:42", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-8000,00", "Зачистка снега" },
                                       { "7", "0", "2020", "1", "2020-02-15", "19:37", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-328,00", "Банк-комиссионный сбор" },
                                       { "8", "8", "2020", "2", "2020-02-07", "21:08", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "500,00", "Членские взносы за текущий год" },
                                       { "9", "33", "2020", "1", "2020-03-06", "15:13", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "300,00", "Земельный налог" },
                                       { "10", "1", "2020", "0", "2020-04-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-583,78", "Сальдо на начало 2021года" },
                                       { "11", "2", "2019", "0", "2019-01-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-5231,77", "Сальдо на начало 2021года" },
                                       { "12", "3", "2019", "0", "2019-01-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-29261,80", "Сальдо на начало 2021года" },
                                       { "13", "4", "2019", "0", "2019-02-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-24996,95", "Сальдо на начало 2021года" },
                                       { "14", "5", "2019", "0", "2019-03-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "Сальдо на начало 2021года" },
                                       { "15", "6", "2019", "0", "2019-03-01", "", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "0,00", "-14220,66", "Сальдо на начало 2021года"} };
            string[] row = new string[dataForTable.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataForTable.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataForTable.GetLength(1); j++)
                    row[j] = dataForTable[i,j];
                cassaTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Строк в базе: " + cassaTable.Rows.Count.ToString());
            DataTable cassaBT = cassaTable.Select("pdate = '" + Convert.ToDateTime("2021-02-26") + "'").CopyToDataTable();
            Console.WriteLine("Выбрано строк с датой 2021-02-26: " + cassaBT.Rows.Count.ToString());
            //Нужно сделать выборку по месяцу
            //И выборку по году
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Познакомьтесь с Entity Framework.

Comment: Предоставьте код, заполняющий DataTable нужными данными. Чтобы мы могли скопировать его и использовать для написания ответа. Создайте `DataTable`, добавьте к нему нужные колонки: `dataTable.Columns.Add(...`, заполните его строками с нужными данными: `dataTable.Rows.Add(...`.

Comment: _Но это вообще не LINQ_ - и что? Зачем тянуть некую технологию туда, где и без неё всё прекрасно работает. Между прочим метод `Select`, который вы использовали выше, тоже не относится к линку - это родной метод дататейбла.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, да все верно, просто до этого использовал cassaTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy() и привязался к LINQу=)))

Comment: Alexander Petrov, технология просто позволяет сделать все в одну строчку кода, да и для развития полезно знать как подобные задачи решаются.

Comment: `для развития полезно знать как подобные задачи решаются` - первый комментарий под вашим вопросом.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, выложил код для теста, как вы просили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Для месяца можно сделать выборку так

```
DataTable cassaMonth = cassaTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToDateTime(r["pdate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM") == Convert.ToDateTime("2021-02").ToString("yyyy-MM")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Для года, в моем случае, так

```
DataTable cassaYear = cassaTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["ypayment"].ToString() == "2021").CopyToDataTable();
```